# How to avoid backslash in java JSONObject before double quotes?

Tags: java, json, double-quotes, backslash

I create some JSONObject using java classes. Lets call it MyJSONObject. It should be the inner String part of another JSON object. Like that:

```
[
    {
        "httpRequest": {...},
        "httpResponse": {
            "headers": {
                "content-type": [
                    "application/json"
                ]
            },
            "body": "MyJSONObject"
        }
]
```

The problem is when i try to put it as string using mapper.writeValueAsString(MyJSONObject) I receive all the quotes with backslash in console body :

```
[
    {
        "httpRequest": {...},
        "httpResponse": {
            "headers": {...},
            "body": "{\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\"}"
        }
]
```

instead of expected:

```
        "body": "{"key":"value","key":"value"}"
```

I tried to replace each quote by quote with backslash, using method `replace("\"", "\\\"")` to my string, but the result is even worse:

```
        "body": "{\\\"key\\\":\\\"value\\\",\\\"key":\\\"value\\\"}"
```

How can i just put my string avoid this backslashes?

Comment: Your "expected" version is invalid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with below approach which will give you expected result.

`JSONObject  subJson = new JSONObject(); subJson.put(“name”, “java”);`

`JSONObject parentJson = new JSONObject() parentJson.put(“company”, ”stack”); parentJson.put(“employees”, subJson);`

`System.out.print(“Final output - ” + parentJson.toString());`